# How to create routes with unique ids in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, routes, mongoose

So i am working on a project with node, express, mongoose en mongodb. I am able to create/save a topic to the db. but when the topic is saved/created i want to redirect the user to the topic details page of that created topic (so basically every created topic has its own unique url based of the id, like so -> localhost:3000/topicdetail/id)

The problem with me is that upon redirecting i get an error saying: Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/Users/Grace/Desktop/QA/views"

So my main question is am i redirect it correctly with its own unique id or am i doing something else wrong. Any help is welcome.

my code is the following:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Topic = require('../models/topic');
var db = require('../config/database');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// render the start/create a new topic view
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('newtopic');
});

// save topic to db
router.post('/',function(req, res, next){
console.log('The post was submitted'); 

var topic = new Topic
({
    "topicTitle":       req.body.topicTitle,
    "topicDescription": req.body.topicDescription,
    "fbId":             req.body.userIdFB,
    "twId":             req.body.userIdTW
})

topic.save(function (err, topic)
{
    if(err){
        return next(err)
        console.log('Failed to save the topic to the database');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('Saved the topic succesfully to the database');
        // each topic has its own unique url 
        res.redirect('/topicdetail/{id}');
    }
})
```

});

module.exports = router;

Comment: >"Unique id" you mean something like the mongoDb document id?

Comment: yes i am trying to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `res.redirect('/topicdetail/{id}');` won't insert any ID. Express won't reformat the string. It takes your defined redirect, in this case `/topicdetail/{id}`and performs it. Just like you would insert it into your browser.

To redirect your detail view you could do something like:
`res.redirect('/topicdetail/' + topic._id);` and replace `topic.id` with something like your document ID or another identifier.

Just a reminder: Your detail route needs a param in the route definition. Example: `app.get('/verification/:token', users);`. The `:token` is your param. More about in the [routing guide.](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick now i get the url with the id of that created topic. only it does not render my details view (still very new with node)

Comment: Thanks and great to hear! As I mentioned, you need a route with matching parameters. Here is a nice route tester to help you with your ideas: http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/

Comment: so my details view page would need the following route then -> http://localhost:3001/topicdetail/:id (it passed the test) but not sure how to handle the detail view route

Comment: It's hard to tell where your problem currently is. You have to define a complete new route for your detail page (probably in your app.js) and in the function that's responsible for the corresponding route you can get your ID using `req.params.id` and do your stuff. It's explained in the express docs.

Comment: ok, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. i appreciated all your help ;-)

Comment: i was succesful in routing the details page but upon rendering the details page with the id param in the url i loose the layout ... don't know why this happens. maybe you have an idea

Comment: It's probably better to start a new question if you encounter another problem that's not related to your first question. What do you mean by "all its layout"? Is just the CSS not available? Or do you see some kind of an error?

Comment: But do you see some HTML from your template?

Comment: Better create a new question with the complete route, your template and the error message, please